# Maintain select Windows environment variables in text file

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I'm working on several Windows computers (mostly Win7) and like to carry my configuration around with me. That configuration is mostly development stuff, like: Where is the main Mercurial repo on my computer? Where are the JAR files? Where is [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com)?

In order to decouple various tools and scripts from the exact location of such things, I point them to environment variables, which I then have to set up for each machine, of course.

As I maintain all my important configuration settings (like for [Vim](http://vim.org)) in Mercurial, I'd like to put the environment variables there as well. In order for this to happen, I need a simple text file representation for editing that ideally I could import per double click into the registry, which is where Windows environment variables reside.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

My first idea was of course to use `regedit` and just export the relevant keys to `sys-env.reg` and `usr-env.reg`. I would then be able to weed out the stuff I wouldn't need to edit, do the edits I want to do, and re-import the environement, and done.

And it works indeed. There's only one problem. A [registry type value of `REG_EXPAND_SZ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884.aspx) is exported as an unreadable and uneditable text representation the underlying binary format (whatever it is).

Hence the question: Does anyone know a better text format for the purposes described above, notably editing? (If not, this is as good as it gets, and I'm already 90 % there, so it's good enough.)

Before you suggest that, I know about the excellent [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/), and I'm actually using it a lot, but this is not what I'm looking for right here.

Comment: The underlying binary format is simply an Unicode string. It's encoded in hexadecimal in `.reg` files for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Just FYI. Windows 7 comes with [setx.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755104(v=ws.10).aspx) to modify environment variables.

Comment: @grawity - Thanks, it occurred to me after posting that it is a representation of a UTF-16 string. Still not convenient to edit, unless you've memorized (at least) the ASCII table. -- Oliver - Thanks, I'm aware of SETX, one of the former Resource Kit tools that now ship by default.